# How to add a new character to an existing String in a sorted order?

Tags: java, android, sorting

Given following characters: "R", "G", "B" and "X". They have to be added, each at a time, to an existing `String` which is length varies from 0 to 5. This length includes the special character `/`. I.e., existing string may look like as:

- `null`
- " " (empty string)
- "G"
- "B/X"
- "G/B"
- "R/G/B"
- etc (other variations of the above)

The final string should always have the order of **"G/R/B/X"**:

- `G` must be the first item.
- `X` must be the last item.
- `R` must come after `G` and before `B`.
- `B` must come after `R`.

Any of these characters may or may not exist.

It looks pretty straightforward if the existing string is only one character:

```
private String sortThemAll(String existingString, String newString) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(existingString)) {
        return newString;
    }

    if (existingString.length() == 1) {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(existingString, newString);
        if (list.contains("G") && list.contains("R")) {
            Collections.sort(list);
        } else {
            Collections.sort(list, Collections.reverseOrder());
        }

        return list.get(0).concat("/").concat(list.get(1));
    }

    if (existingString.length() == 3) { // e.g., "B/X"
        // Assuming that existingString is already sorted
        if ("G".equals(newString)) {
            // G should always be the first item on the list
            return newString.concat("/").concat(existingString);
        }
        if ("X".equals(newString)) {
            // X should always be the last item on the list
            return existingString.concat("/").concat(newString);
        }
        /*** I don't know how I should proceed from this point ***/
    }

    return existingString.concat("/").concat(newString);
}
```

I can't see any pattern in this problem, all I can think of is several nested `if/else` blocks. How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: try use List<Sting> listString = new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: @andreich, how will I sort that `listString` then? :)

Comment: Collections.sort(listString);

Comment: And that will sort the list in alphabetical order? As you may have noticed the characters in the final string is not sorted alphabetically.

Comment: You could write your own Comparator: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Comment: yes, use custom Object, where you override method equals(Object) with you rule

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose you have this String `"B/R/G"`. I would follow the following steps to order it:

- Split the String on `"/"`, to get an array:

  ```
  String str = "B/R/G";
  String[] arr = str.split("/");
  ```
- I'll write my own comparator. But since the order is not a natural order, I'll use a string for getting the required order of characters:

  ```
  final String order = "GRBX";
  ```
- Then I'll sort the array based on the following Comparator:

  ```
  Comparator<String> comparator = new Comparator<String>() {
      @Override
      public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
          // Get the index of both strings from the `order` string.
          // Lesser index means comes before.
          return order.indexOf(s1) - order.indexOf(s2);
      }
  };

  Arrays.sort(arr, comparator);
  ```
- Then I'll join the array elements again on `"/"`, to get the final ordered String.

You just need to make sure, you don't split a `null` string.

For your given strings, you'll get the following lists:

```
"B/R/G"  -> [G, R, B]
"R/G/B"  -> [G, R, B]
"G/B"    -> [G, B]
"B/X"    -> [B, X]
"G"      -> G
""       -> ""
null     -> // Handle this as required
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't operate on strings at all. Instead I would create an enum and class with a `toString` method. It will not make you sort anything.

```
enum Something { R, G, B, X }

class Marks {

    private EnumSet<Soomething> markers = EnumSet.noneOf(Something.class);

    public void addSth(Something s) {
        markers.add(s);
    }

    public String toString() {
        if (markers.isEmpty())
            return "";
        ...
    }
}
```